# How to combine values in textview

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement, switch-statement

Would it be possible to write this type of action somehow shorter? I have tried the switch but "contains" is disturbing

```
                    if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("10")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                }
                if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("9")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                }
                if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("8")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                }
                if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("7")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                }
                if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("6")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                }
                if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("5")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
                }
                if (TvC.getText().toString().contains("4")) {
                    layoutcenter.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);

                }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Is it a count down?

Comment: you can probably use `Integer.parseInt( TvC.getText().toString() );` and then use switch.. but maybe no need for switch since all cases do the same code. Just have to check if it is a number from 4 to 10 and do one clause.